# Fast matrix vector multiplication for single shot use in Julia

Tags: julia

I need to perform many steps of matrix vector multiplication with a matrix that changes at each step. There is a procedure for generating the matrix elements at each step, but since that involves looping over all elements it wouldn't seem efficient to subsequently pass these elements to matrix multiplication.

At the moment I am evaluating the matrix elements within the same nested double loop that does the multiplication. Is there a better way?

Comment: Any sample code?

Comment: Which version of Julia do you use?